# Allow accepting multiple answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

For the question [Why loops show low iteration rate when iterations are minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091875/why-loops-show-low-iteration-rate-when-iterations-are-minimum), I got two answers and both are acceptable. But I am not able to show support for both.

In our field there may be various methods for solving the same problem. So it is better to allow more than one accepted answer for the same question.

I think it's implemented like this (only one accepted answer) because accepting the one which is exact to the question is not the approximate, isn't it?

Comment: On the one occasion this happened to me, I upvoted both and tossed a coin for the accept.

Comment: You could also edit the question or post a comment saying that you think that these two answers are equally well suited. Then either toss a coin and choose the one answer with lower rep (this account is more likely to benefit from it) in case you really equally like both answers. I mean this can surely happen.

Comment: Seven years later, same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866145/split-string-by-commas-only-not-leaving-whitespaces where the OP writes: _"I thought stackoverflow.com would give me an opportunity to accept more than 1 answer"_. I suppose one (or multiple) amber ticks, alongside one green tick would be out of the question...?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can show support for both by upvoting both.  The idea of an accepted answer is to say "this is the answer which worked best for me".  Which should only be one.  If others think another answer is better and the question is important, the others will get slowly upvoted.

Comment: You should upvote them all, @Sujith. Then accept the one that you chose to use. At least, that's what I would do.

Comment: @SujithKarivelil If your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid (and different) answers, it's probably too broad for the Stack Overflow format anyway.

Comment: What should I do, if I accepted an answer, and then (later) somebody posted an even better answer?

Comment: Guidelines like “what worked best for me” or “what I ended up using” do not always make sense: often the question is not “I must *do* X in practical context Y *today*” but rather a general learning question. There isn’t always a “best answer” either: often the question is about listing things (advantages for X, use cases for Y, etc.); or, it is a seemingly simple question but answers can get pretty thorough. In situations like these, you can have many equally good and *complementary* answers.

Answer (score -12):

The accept vote is essentially a public, strong upvote of the OP of the question.

I think it would be a nice idea, if

- no accept vote would exist any more
- but, the vote of the OP would be public (voted up, down or abstained).
- maybe the up- or downvote of the OP could have a stronger weight as the ordinary community votes (I am thinking on a +20 for ups and -4 for downs).

Comment: "Pipe"?  What pipe?

Comment: @Cerbrus Accept vote.

Comment: I've never hear that referred to as "Pipe"...

Comment: @Cerbrus Ok, I changed it to "accept vote".

Comment: @peterh It's a check-mark, by the way.

Comment: @Daedalus Well, it is right, I agree that. However, there is no way to handle the questions whose OP disappeared and left the question open. It is a regularly coming problem on the mother meta, and the SE intentionally ignores this, saying like this: *"accept pipe is only a special vote of the OP, the voting score is important"*... The result is abandoned questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13/1783163), in whose sea the really interesting, long unsolved problems are lost. What a crap!

Comment: Well, nice to see that our downvoter herd works very reliable, as always.

Comment: @peterh I'm not here to comment on anything other than it looks nothing like a pipe.  The word pipe has always been used to describe the pipe(`|`), not a check mark, which is what the accept symbol is.  Which by the way, you're the only one who's referred to it as an 'accept pipe' on SE.

Comment: @Daedalus Sorry, I used always this word and it is not an own invention. I can't remember, where I've learned it. Yes, pipe is used also for "`|`", but in a Unix/Linux content and not in a GUI context. Only on the SE caused it sometimes little troubles. But it is not a problem, so I will use the word checkmark for that in the future.

Comment: Anyway, the OP can currently choose to give either 10, 15 or 25 points to an answer, not counting bounties, so I see no reason why you would want to have the choice to give 20 points instead.

Comment: @MrLister My opinion is about the overweighting of the OPs upvote. There is nothing about the choices of the OPs. You simply misunderstood the post.